# How to download voice from google translate with c# webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, text-to-speech

I want get data and to client(base64 dataurl) from google translate tts using c# web api, so i create this code :

```
public Object Get()
        {
             byte[] wc =  new WebClient().DownloadData(
                new Uri("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello%20World&tl=en-us"));
            return new { Data = Convert.ToBase64String(wc) };
        }
```

but i get error :

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

how to solve this?